# go-ini package key-value delimiter not found error

Tags: go

I am using go-ini package to parse the Ansible-playbook file.
While trying to execute the following code, am getting the error saying,

> key-value delimiter not found: 172.16.1.2

**Go code:**

```
conf, err := ini.Load(inventoryFilePath)
if err != nil {
    return errors.New("Unable to read file: " + err.Error())
}
nodeSection, err := conf.GetSection("vm_master")
if err != nil {
    return errors.New("Unable to get section: " + err.Error())
}
```

**Input File:**

```
[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_ssh_user=root
ansible_ssh_pass=password

[vm_master]
172.16.1.2

[vm_client]
172.16.1.3
172.16.1.4
```

Comment: The error tells you the exact problem. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the LoadOptions{} before the LoadSources call fixes this issue.
And we can get the values in the section using `section.Body()` call.

```
loadOptions := ini.LoadOptions{}
loadOptions.UnparseableSections = []string{"vm_master", "vm_client"}

nodeConfig, err := ini.LoadSources(loadOptions, inventoryFilePath)
```